# What are the reasons to create UIView subclass?

Tags: ios, object-oriented-design, objective-c, inheritance, view

I've noticed that there are a lot of UIView subclasses in my legacy project. Mostly the only reason of such a subclass is to split bigger view into custom subviews and provide layout for its subviews and delegation of UIButtons actions through the view delegate protocol. So I'm wondering, is it a correct design?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very common reason to create a UIView subclass is so that one can specify a drawRect method to do some Core Graphics drawing into a view.  Another reason might to implement touch delegates, such as if you want to do something within a specific view area too specialized for a gesture recognizer.

Partitioning objects (such as views) into logical groupings, possibly into a hierarchy, is usually considered good coding practice, as it helps isolates the scope of any changes or bugs.

Answer (score 1):

If your view is just a container of other views, then you better use a regular (not subclassed) UIView. You compose the view (or load then nib) from a subclassed view controller.

Exceptions: when to subclass UIView:

- for custom drawing
- non standard touch responses (beyond the capabilities of the gesture recognizers)

Answer (score 1):

In early iOS, there was no ViewController. Some things we might now do with a ViewController today were done by the view; it sounds like some of your view classes are doing things like that.

On the whole, it's not a terrible code smell if the subclass is small. When the subclass gets too messy, sprout new classes to manage the aggregation (MyController) and delegation (MyViewDelegate) responsibilities.

Answer (score -1):

In XCode, every UIButton, UiLabel are UIViews only those predefined UIViews, so when you want to add those to your ViewController, they will be added like:

```
[self.view addSubview:aView];
```

We can also create custom UIViews which allow you to design your own complex views like tableViews, GridViews, Charts and so on...

Comment: It does not relate to my Q at all.

Answer (score -1):

if you can manage all your view then there is no harm to keep number of subviews..

you can refer View hierarchy..

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/WorkingWithAViewHierarchy/WorkingWithAViewHierarchy.html

In one of my project i had 10 subviews which were added based on my button click...

I searched and found there is no limitation given for subviews...